# Number of Vectors at a Specific Hamming Distance from 2 Vectors

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let binary Vector *A* of length *n* be the all zero vector. Another vector *B* is of same length is at a Hamming distance *x* from A. Find all number of vectors that are at distance *y* from *A* and *z* from *B* in terms of *x, y and z*.

So far I have come up with the following. The resulting vectors must contain y 1's.

${a \choose b}*{c \choose d}$

where

1. a = No. of 1's in B
2. c = No. of 0's in B
3. b,d such that b+d=z
4. a-b+d=y

I can't seem to simplify the above expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the resulting vector has to have $y\ 1$s.  To get there, you need to flip $b$ of the $1$s that are in $B$, leaving $x-b\ 1$s, then flip $z-b$ of the original $0$s, which gives $x+z-2b\ 1$s.  We therefore need $x+z-2b=y, b=(x-y+z)/2$.  The first thing we note is that $x+y+z$ has to be even or there is no solution.  Assuming there is a solution there are $x \choose b$ ways to choose the $1$s to flip and $n-x \choose z-b$ to choose the zeros to flip.  This gives 
$$b=\frac 12(x-y+z)\\
\text{Number of ways }{x \choose b}{n-x\choose z-b}$$

Comment: Thanks...slight correction it should be -y instead of +y

Comment: @user36685:  You are right.  I dropped a sign.  Thanks.